# How can I deploy a index.html file in microsoft azure cloud?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, filezilla

I have a index.html file and I want to deploy it in azure. so I created web app in azure and connected it to filezilla  but when I drag my index.html file to filezilla hosts it is showing disconnected from server  and connection aborted. How can I overcome this?

Comment: You need to elaborate more. Is it Azure Web apps that you are using ? How are you connecting to filezilla? What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: yes, I created  a azure web app  and in that  through FTP  I connected to filezilla  by giving credentials like user name , host name and password  which we created in azure web app. I want to publish that index.html in azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above . In Azure App services ,  Go to deployment center and use choose FTP . Pick credentials to connect to filezilla and Simply drag and drop your index.html.

[image]

Comment: After dragging my index.html it is showing "disconnected  from server" and "connection aborted".  Do I need to add any files along with index.html??

Comment: no other files required.  you don't have any firewall blocking the connection? when you connect for first time do you see a default file already available in app service?

Comment: I don't have any firewall blocking issue . yes I have seen a default file already available in app service.

Comment: means you are getting connected first time. give your app service restart.  are you using linux or windows os for app service? if still doesn't work try recreating if you can

Comment: ok , thanks for the help  and I am using windows  for app service.